# elasticsearch-dsl using from and size

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm using python 2.7 with Elasticsearch-DSL package to query my elastic cluster.

Trying to add "from and limit" capabilities to the query in order to have pagination in my FE which presents the documents elastic returns but 'from' doesn't work right (i.e. I'm not using it correctly I spouse).

The relevant code is:

```
s = Search(using=elastic_conn, index='my_index'). \
       filter("terms", organization_id=org_list)

    hits = s[my_from:my_size].execute() # if from = 10, size = 10 then I get 0 documents, altought 100 documents match the filters.
```

My index contains 100 documents.
even when my filter match all results (i.e nothing is filtered out), if I use
`my_from = 10` and `my_size = 10`, for instance, then I get nothing in hits (no matching documents)

Why is that? Am I misusing the from?

Documentation states:

from and size parameters. The from parameter defines the offset from the first result you want to fetch. The size parameter allows you to configure the maximum amount of hits to be returned.

So it seems really straightforward, what am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the query generated by your code and the response json.

Comment: I think I understood what the problem was. It seems like `from` relates to results after applying the `limit` filter. Meaning if I ask for `from = 10` and `size = 10` then it will first fetch 10 results and then do offset of 10 on this subset and therefore I eventually get 0 documents. So what I should do is `from = 10` and `size = 20` and that will give me documents 10-20 which is what I wanted. Thx anyway.

Comment: This is how from/size works. Assume you have a query which matches 24 documents (0 to 23). Since by default `from = 0` and `size = 10` elastic will return first 10 docs (i.e. 0 to 9). Now if you set `from = 10` for the same query and `size = 10`, elastic will return doc 11th to 20th (i.e. 10 to 19). Again for the same query if you set `from = 20` and `size = 10`, elastic will return remaining 4 records (20 to 23).

Comment: Well, that's not the behaviour I experience, For `from=10`, `size=10` I get 0 docs. Perhaps it's an issue with Elasticsearch-DSL version (6.2.1). How can I further investigate this issue?

Comment: Execute the match all query `{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}`. Paste the response here. Then I might be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this question can be found in their documentation under the [Pagination Section of the Search DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination):

> **Pagination**
>
> To specify the from/size parameters, use the Python slicing API:
>
> ```
> s = s[10:20]
>
> # {"from": 10, "size": 10}
> ```

The correct usage of these parameters with the Search DSL is just as you would with a Python list, slicing from the starting index to the end index. The size parameter would be implicitly defined as the end index minus the start index.

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: Try to execute it first, then use slicing i.e. `s=s.execute() s=s[my_from:my_size]`

Answer (score 5):

Try to pass `from` and `size` params as below:

```
search = Search(using=elastic_conn, index='my_index'). \
        filter("terms", organization_id=org_list). \
        extra(from_=10, size=20)
result = search.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the documentation that there is 1-to-1 mapping `s[from:size]`. However that isn't the case, as in python splicing `s[10:10]` is only empty. You need to give it as `s[10:20]` i.e., `s[from : from+size]`.